# c# serialport read functions not reading data

Tags: c#

I dont know where is the problem , I open the serial port and send message it work fine , but when I click the receive button , it does not receive any thing
i use all these functions `Read() , ReadLine() , ReadExisting() ,ReadTo()`
none of them works for me.

```
private void sendBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!serialPort1.IsOpen)
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
            serialPort1.Write(textBox1.Text);
        }
        catch (Exception ez )
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ez.Message);
        }    
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            serialPort1.Write(textBox1.Text+"\n");
            textBox1.Text = "";             
        }
        catch (Exception ez)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ez.Message);
        }        
    }
}
```

Then this is the receive data button code

```
private void receiveBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        textBox2.Text = serialPort1.ReadExisting();
    }
    catch (TimeoutException z)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(z.Message)      
    } 
}
```

[image: diagram 1]

Comment: is it open when you try to read ?

Comment: do you know there's incoming data on your serial port?

Comment: try to extend your post to be a minimal, complete, verifyable example [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505197/1132334) so we could reproduce. For example, how is `serialPort1` created and configured?

Comment: yes i open it when form load

Comment: i create the serial port by serialport control in toolbox

Comment: i want to read the mesg that i send by send button , there is no other device is attached to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Serial port send data imediatly. So you ned to read at same moment at different port which recevied this data. 
If you need to test it locally you need some serial port loopback software, which can add virtual ports and make virtual connection between them.

**You must have 2 connected serial ports.**

You can use [this](https://freevirtualserialports.com/) software to create 2 serial ports and connect them. And your app cans write to one port and read second.

Comment: if you have a hardware serial port, you could also build a "loopback adapter" - shorting RX and TX pins. Then you can send data to the port and read it back.