# Continues Reading Inputstream (serialport/tty)

Tags: java, android, serial-port

I am continuously reading data from serialport/tty. Serialport spitting the data every 40 milliseconds. I am using java InputStream to read the data.

```
    static final int buffersize = 208;
 buffer = new byte[buffersize];
    int dataSize = mInputStream.read(buffer);
                if (dataSize > 0)
                {
                    fpgaData = new String(buffer, 0, buffer.length);
                }
```

But most of the time I don't get full data in one read.
E.g. 0000001 0000044 0001BF7 0000091 0000210 0000000 00000FF is the full data. 
How to make sure that I get full desire data single read.

Answer (score 0):

That is the serial port specification.

You have to design and program with consideration that one data can be notified separately and it can happen that multiple data are notified at once.

Comment: @Muhammad Rizwan nycghuman, For example this is a C# article, but you can use the way of thinking. [Parsing/formatting data from serial port - C#](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9505197/9014308)

Comment: Thank you so much for guiding me. I was able to extract the desire data from buffer if matches specific pattern.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it with BufferReader instread of InputStream reader.

```
try
                {
                    BufferedReader bufferedReader = serialPort.GetBufferStream();
                    if (bufferedReader != null)
                    {
                        String contents = bufferedReader.readLine();
                        while (contents != null)
                        {   
                            contents = bufferedReader.readLine();

                        }
                    }

                } catch (IOException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return;
                }
            }
```